# Multiple public directories in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In meteor, I can have multiple `client`, multiple `server` directories, etc. (ex: `/foo/client/` and `/bar/client/`) I segment my app by behavior, for example `/users/*` for user management, subs, methods, UI, etc., or `/inv/*` for inventory management, collections, subs, methods, UI, etc., and all other parts of my app. This allow some code organisation and separate components and methods so the app will scale better in the long term.

This works quite well so far, however I need to add some assets to each segments of the app and, since the `/public` directory content is copied over `/.meteor/.local/build/programs/web.browser/app`, I wanted to know if it was possible to have multiple public directories, where all files would be merged into the build target?

Comment: I think you will have to end up having proper folders `/public/users`, `/public/inv` etc. The less magic - the easier for other developers to dig through the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't currently possible to have multiple public directories within a single application. This is disallowed by Meteor's [Isobuild](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/tools/isobuild) system. If you want to maintain separate `/public` directories with related component functionality, then you should look into leveraging [Meteor packages](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html). Packages can have their own public assets. The ["Building Large Apps: Tips"](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Building-Large-Apps-Tips-d8PQ848nLyE) hackpad talks about how you can leverage a "packages-for-everything" approach with Meteor and achieve the type of component separation (with separate public assets) you're looking for. That being said most of the Meteor community has either moved, or is starting to move, away from a "packages-for-everything" approach. The launch of Meteor 1.3 and ES2015 module support has made this approach mostly unnecessary (with a few exceptions, like maintaining separate public assets).

Comment: Thank you for the information. Most of my app "packages" do not require public assets, I was wondering if I could keep those who do within their own directories. I agree that "packages-for-everything" is a bit too much, and I would rather not go down this path.So, I'll just stick with a single public directory, then.